# Random python3 как сделать разные числа

Tags: python, случайные-числа

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу заполнить список 30 рандомными числами из диапазона (35000, 110000), чтобы рядом стоящие отличались друг от друга. Я пробовал random.randint, но числа получаются очень похожими! 
Как можно зарандомить так чтобы числа отличались, то есть было например [35000, 90000, 45000, 100000....]

Comment: Не знаю как там с нагрузкой )), загнать в массив, перемешать и достать первые 30

Answer (score 1):

Берём предыдущее случайное. Прибавляем случайное в диапазоне от минимального до максимального зазора. Нормализуем в диапазон.

Пример.

Диапазон (35000, 110000). Соответственно дельта 110000-35000=75000.

Минимальный зазор 10000. Соответственно ширина диапазона генерации 75000 - 2 * 10000 = 55000.

Скажем, очередное случайное 51234.

Генерим случайное от нуля до диапазона генерации. Например, получаем 0,123456789 * 55000 = 6790.

Следующее случайное будет 51234 + 6790 = 58024.

Генерим случайное от нуля до диапазона генерации. Например, получаем 0,987654321 * 55000 = 54321.

Следующее случайное будет 58024 + 54321 = 112345. Оно вылетает за диапазон.

Нормализуем. Следующее случайное после нормализации будет 112345 - 110000 + 35000 = 37345.

Answer (score 0):

можно например так

```
random.randrange(35000, 110000, step)
```

и указать step какой-нибудь большой или рандомный

`step = random.randint(1000, 9999)`

и чтобы для каждого следующего числа брался новый step

```
array = []
while len(array) != 30:
    step = random.randint(1000, 9999)
    rand = random.randrange(35000, 110000, step)
    array.append(rand)
print(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так:

```
import random
s = set()
while len(s) != 30:
    r = random.randrange(35000, 110000, 999)
    s.add(r)
s = list(s)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего наверно циклом дергать рандом и сверять с предыдущими, пока 30 уникальных не наберется
Это не рабочий код, просто алгоритм примерный
Если нужны круглые числа как в примере, то воспользоваться делением

```
     $arr = array();
     while(true) {
     $a = rand(35000, 110000);
     if(array_search($a, $arr)) {continue;}
     else {array_push($arr, $a)}
     if(array_count($arr) < 30) {continue;} else {break;}
     }
```

Comment: Вопрос по языку Python, у вас кажется PHP

Comment: Ну алгоритм главное, не думаю что трудно перевести

Comment: Но и алгоритм не соответствует исходному вопросу `(:` См. мой ответ для понимания.

Comment: Я думаю про "рядом стоящие" не надо понимать буквально. Все равно при таком диапазоне их не будет. Но сделать чтобы иногда совпадали НЕ рядом стоящие тоже проще простого

Answer (score 0):

Почему-то все ответы упускают важный вопрос OP:

> чтобы рядом стоящие отличались друг от друга ... числа получаются очень похожими

Т.е, хочется исключить не абсолютно одинаковые числа, а в неком диапазоне. И говорится не про весь список, а соседние. Поэтому:

```py
import random

# Здесь будет итоговый список
result = []
# Сохраняем предыдущее число для того, 
# чтобы соседние значения были разными
prev = 0

# Выполняем основной цикл пока не наберётся нужное число элементов
while len(result) < 30:
    new = prev
    # Пока числа слишком похожие в заданном диапазоне
    while abs(new-prev) < 10000:
        # То выбираем новое следующее число
        # Последний аргумент randrange для того, чтобы числа были круглыми
        new = random.randrange(35000, 110000, 100)
    # Когда число найдётся, сохраняем его в результат
    result.append(new)
    # И сохраняем как прошлое значение
    prev = new

# Выводим результат
print(result)
```

Получаем список, где соседние числа отличаются минимум на 10 000:

> [104800, 68800, 94400, 53000, 72900, 52100, 86500, 56100, 43200, 92900, 53000, 105300, 61000, 72200, 39200, 75300, 36700, 49500, 105800, 72500, 83900, 46300, 94600, 48600, 61400, 90300, 75100, 47500, 77200, 50400]